# PostgreSQL - HyperLogLog extension not found for windows

Tags: postgresql, hyperloglog

Can someone explain in a better way (well, in a way for dummies to understand), or more correctly how to install HyperLogLog hll extension for PostgreSQL installed on windows 10/11.

When running CREATE EXTENSION hll;

I get:

Query 1 ERROR: ERROR: could not open extension control file "hll.control": No such file or directory

I am new at this, so this documentation https://github.com/citusdata/postgresql-hll did not helped me a lot.

Comment: I think that installing hll on Windows is unreasonably difficult.  I doubt there is a way for dummies to do it successfully.